# Best way to load thousands of data in a fast way

Tags: php, android, mysql

i have this Mobile app built with android where data is stored in the server using PHP and MySQL.

- Android - Mobile App
- PHP - API
- MySQL - Database

In Mobile App, we have newsfeed. We have already 150 datas. We recoded the time, its loading 20secs of 150 datas.

Im thinking that i should load only first 10 datas and when scroll down, loads another.

What do you suggest?

Another question. Does MySQL Join makes the query fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can fetch the small chunk of data. For a this you need to handle the query in such a manner that it accept a page number for the data.

For example if you are fetching the record 1-10, you will pass the page number 1 and accordingly you will get a result.

Also you make use of [Endless Adapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) in your android app

Comment: I search this question again I never thought I had this, its really helpful! haha

Comment: hi please upvote thanks!